# what is stroke and stroke width in SVG and how is it rendered in the HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg

```
<svg width="400" height="400" style="background-color:green">

   <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" fill="yellow"></circle></svg>

<svg width="400" height="400" style="background-color:green">

   <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="50" fill="yellow"></circle></svg>


<svg width="400" height="400" style="background-color:green">

   <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="100" fill="yellow"></circle></svg>


<svg width="400" height="400" style="background-color:green">

   <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="150" fill="yellow"></circle></svg>
```

[image: with stroke-width 5][image: with stroke-width 50][image: with stroke-width 100][image: with stroke-width 150]

I've just started learning about SVGs and I am little confused about stroke and stroke width, and how they are rendered. 
In the developer tools, it looks strange whenever I increase the stroke width, the circle holding area increases but the dimensions are 100x100 always. 
I want to know if the stroke width is being added to the radius or am I confused on its rendering. Someone need to explain the concept behind the svgs or direct me to some pages so that i can learn deep

Comment: The stroke is "centered" on the outline of the circle defined by the center and radius: half of the stroke is on the inside of the circle, and half on the outside, so the apparent "outer" size of the circle grows when the stroke width grows. This is the same as with a single line: it's larger when you increase the stroke width.

Comment: thanks, i have understood that now with your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SVG stroke Property**

- The stroke property defines the color of a line, text or outline of
  an element

**SVG stroke-width Property**

- The stroke-width property defines the thickness of a line, text or
  outline of an element

Check this w3schools [article](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_stroking.asp) for svg properties

> SVG is XML based, which means that every element is available within
>   the SVG DOM. You can attach JavaScript event handlers for an element.
>
> In SVG, each drawn shape is remembered as an object. If attributes of
>   an SVG object are changed, the browser can automatically re-render the
>   shape.

That problem that is showing to you is because the maximum stroke-width that you can apply to a circle with the radius 50px is 100px so it's a simple math. Your max stroke-width for `r=50px` is `2*r` so it's `100px`.

When you add stroke-width = 150 it means that the stroke-width radius need to be bigger to hande that. Chrome shows the circle as `100x100` and that's true the circle radius doesn't change only the stroke radius changes.

To prove that just change your stroke-width to `500px` and you will clearly see how this is working and you will understand this.

This is also known as bug so you have this open issue in this [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239860)

Comment: I know that, but how is the circle going off when stroke width is 100 and it appears again when stroke width is 150. I want to know this mechanicsm

Comment: @3yRuL3z did you get it now or you want more explanation ?

Comment: yep I have got it.. was confused by the bug.